# Why can I create generic object without specifying its type in any way and when type cannot be inferred?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

(nevermind:) <strike>it's illegal: `HashSet<> f;`</strike>

it's legal: `new HashSet<>();`

From type inference documentation:

> You can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor
>   of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters (<>) **as long
>   as the compiler can infer the type arguments from the context**.

But a compiler cannot infer type argument in second example, so why does it compile?

Comment: _You can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters_ That's not what you're doing in your first snippet.

Comment: Also, it can infer. It infers `Object`. That rules of type inference are extremely long, but that's what `new HashSet<>()` reduces to.

Comment: What gives you the impression that the compiler cannot infer type argument in second example?

Comment: @EngineerDollery I thought that inferring works only when there is already some code which defines generic type and then you don't have to repeat yourself in next statements. I thought that when there is no such code, then there is no context to use for inferring. But now I see inferring is a broader thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics is a compile-time construct. That is, it's used to enforce that a given variable or method can only work with a specific type or set of types. In your case the compiler can "infer" the broadest type - `Object`, since the `HashSet` is not being assigned or returned, so the types will never be used at compile time. And at runtime the types are meaningless due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).